# Casting Object array into String array throws ClassCastException

Tags: java, arrays, string, object, classcastexception

```
List<String> list = getNames();//this returns a list of names(String).

String[] names = (String[]) list.toArray(); // throws class cast exception.
```

I don't understand why ? Any solution, explanation is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

This is because the parameterless `toArray` produces an array of `Object`s. You need to call the overload which takes the output array as the parameter, and pass an array of `String`s, like this:

```
String[] names = (String[]) list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

In Java 5 or newer you can drop the cast.

```
String[] names = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

Comment: Isn't the cast superfluous here? Don't have a compiler on hand but I don't see why not. Also a link to some explanation about co/contra variance would make the answer complete I think.

Comment: @Voo Only in Java 5 and later; before Java 5 it was necessary.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I wasn't aware Java 5 was still used commonly.

Comment: Oh right that function already existed before java 5, so yes it makes a difference there. Although I hope nobody is really using java 1.4 anymore

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to cast from a class of `Object[]`. The class itself is an array of type `Object`. You would have to cast individually, one-by-one, adding the elements to a new array.

Or you could use the method already implemented for that, by doing this:

```
list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```